# Dadata, уплывающее название города в label при повторном открытии окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

В модальном окне bootstrap имеется список городов select. В input добавляем поиск по кладр коду, в который также в label добавляем название города. При открытии окна в первый раз label располагается правильно, при повторном открытии - label уходит вниз за пределы input, но возвращается на место при установки курсора в input или смене города. Код

```js
$('.addBtn').on('click', function() {

  let kladr = $('#city').find(':selected').val().toString();
  let city = $('#city').find(':selected').text();
  enforceCity(kladr, city);
  
  $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
})

let token = "7fd18aaabd7d53ffa4846e4521c1f736c13490eb";

$("#address").suggestions({
  token: token,
  type: "ADDRESS"
});

$('#city').on('change', function(){
  let kladr = $('#city').find(':selected').val().toString();
  let city = $('#city').find(':selected').text();
  enforceCity(kladr, city);
})


function enforceCity(kladr, city){
 let tempSearch = $("#address").suggestions();
 tempSearch.clear();
 tempSearch.setOptions({
  constraints: {
    label: city,
   locations: { 
    kladr_id: kladr 
   }
  },
  restrict_value: true
 });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@19.8.0/dist/css/suggestions.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@19.8.0/dist/js/jquery.suggestions.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus addBtn"></span>

<div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Выбрать город:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="city">
            <option value="7700000000000">Челябинск</option>
            <option value="5200000100000">Нижний Новгород</option>
            <option value="6300000100000">Самара</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="address">Адрес</label>
          <input type="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Введите адрес">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в анимации при появлении модального окна. Скрипт рассчитывает позицию элементов во время анимации, поэтому ошибается.

Надо обновить позицию элементов, после появления окна.

```js
$('.addBtn').on('click', function() {

  let kladr = $('#city').find(':selected').val().toString();
  let city = $('#city').find(':selected').text();

  $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
  enforceCity(kladr, city)
})

let token = "7fd18aaabd7d53ffa4846e4521c1f736c13490eb";

$("#address").suggestions({
  token: token,
  type: "ADDRESS"
});

$('#city').on('change', function() {
  let kladr = $('#city').find(':selected').val().toString();
  let city = $('#city').find(':selected').text();
  enforceCity(kladr, city);
})


function enforceCity(kladr, city) {
  let tempSearch = $("#address").suggestions();
  console.log(tempSearch);
  tempSearch.clear();
  tempSearch.setOptions({
    constraints: {
      label: city,
      locations: {
        kladr_id: kladr
      }
    },
    restrict_value: true
  });
  setTimeout(() => tempSearch.fixPosition(), 150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@19.8.0/dist/css/suggestions.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@19.8.0/dist/js/jquery.suggestions.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus addBtn"></span>

<div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Выбрать город:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="city">
            <option value="7700000000000">Челябинск</option>
            <option value="5200000100000">Нижний Новгород</option>
            <option value="6300000100000">Самара</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="address">Адрес</label>
          <input type="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Введите адрес">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит как костыль, если честно) Причем, если у вас стоит 150, то при минимальной задержки в анимации - все опять начинает сползать)

Comment: Конечно костыль. Не костыльных вариантов нету. Есть другие костыли: убрать анимацию, использовать анимацию на jquery(что бы знать, когда она завершится), подписаться на `animationEnd` событие модалки. Использовать другой suggestion. Выбирайте на ваш вкус :-)